# ContextualVersionConflict issue with azureml-automl-core in AzureML designer

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am using AutoML called via Custom Python Script module in AzureML designer.
For that, I need to install automl packages:

```
os.system(f"pip install azureml-sdk[automl]==1.0.85 --upgrade")
```

It worked correctly, but now when I call automl training I received this error:

```
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (azureml-dataprep 1.3.2 (/azureml-envs/azureml_8d08fe76aaa5abe0ec642fd2de335a04/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('azureml-dataprep<1.2.0a,>=1.1.37a'), {'azureml-automl-core'})
```

Looks like there was an update in azureml-dataprep to version 1.3.2 which is not compatible with azureml-sdk[automl]==1.0.85.

1. Would it be possible to add AutoML packages as default package in AzureML designer?
2. Would it be possible to update azureml-sdk version in AzureML designer?
3. Is there any workaround right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after release new version of AzureML SDK in designer and update script to:

```
os.system(f"pip install azureml-sdk[automl]==1.4.0 --upgrade")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain a bit more on what you want to achieve in designer by calling AutoML SDK? I'm wondering what specific capability you are leveraging in designer compared with using AutoML SDK directly in notebook. It would help us better understand the scenario and provide an appropriate solution:)

Thanks,
Lu

Comment: I would like to have a tool for forecasting which can be used with non-developer users. AML Designer is a great tool but is not strong enough. That's why I create own AutoML module. I suppose that you have a plan to add this module to Designer but right now I have to use mine.